# Vee-validate yup.when() not requiring field when it should

Tags: vue.js, yup, vee-validate

When hasWebsite is 'yes', websiteAddress should be required. However, it is not with this code (typescript):

```
    const validationSchema = {
      name: string().required(),
      message: string().required(),
      hasWebsite: string().required(),
      email: string().email().required(),
      websiteAddress: string().when('hasWebsite', {
        is: 'yes',
        then: (schema) => schema.required(),
        otherwise: (schema) => schema.notRequired()
      })
    }
```

Here is the element where hasWebsite is set:

```html
    <BaseSelect
      :choices="['yes', 'no']"
      v-model="hasWebsite"
      label="Do you currently have a website?"
      :selectedOption="hasWebsite"
      :error="errors.hasWebsite"
    />
```

And here is more potentially relevant code:

```
    const formValidation = useForm({
      validationSchema: validationSchema,
      initialValues: {
        hasWebsite: 'no',
        websiteAddress: '',
        name: '',
        email: '',
        message: ''
      }
    })
    
    const { value: email } = useField('email')
    const { value: hasWebsite } = useField('hasWebsite')
    const { value: websiteAddress } = useField('websiteAddress')
    const { value: name } = useField('name')
    const { value: message } = useField('message')
```